# What is the difference between lepture/authlib OAuth2 Client and Session?

Tags: rest, api, oauth-2.0, authlib

I am implementing an OAuth2 Client app to connect to [this](https://github.com/authlib/example-oauth2-server) server. So far I've managed to get resource /api/me using Authlib's [OAuth2Session](https://github.com/lepture/authlib/blob/master/authlib/client/oauth2_session.py) instance. I've tried it with [OAuthClient](https://github.com/lepture/authlib/blob/master/authlib/client/client.py), but it didn't work, although the Client class has methods like `put, post, get, delete` so it is suited for accessing resources I suppose. :/

So what is the difference, why am I able to access `/api/me` using Session's instance and unable with Client's instance?

Here's my code:

```
    def api_me_get2(token):
    print("========================================")
    print("Sending 2nd GET request to get protected data of me")

    oauth2_client = OAuthClient(
        client_id='ySFTzBKLo0XTaK2tQL9ls4Fc',
        client_secret='vq8vMZplY4J00FrxKx4ynV2mhmL2zzjMzP1U2bXZPhQRcmJl',
        api_base_url=_url(""),
        access_token_url=_url(f"/oauth/token"),
        authorize_url=_url("/oauth/authorize"),
        client_kwargs={"scope":"profile"},
#        client_kwargs={'scope': 'user:email'},
    )

    new_token = oauth2_client.fetch_access_token();
    print(f"New token \"{new_token}\"")
    # FORM data
    '''
    payload = {
        "token":f"{token}"
    }
    print(f"PAYLOAD=\"{payload}\"")
    r = requests.get(_url(f"/api/me"), data=payload, params=payload)
    print(f"RESPONSE {r.status_code}")
    print(f"r.url={r.url}")
    print(f"r.text={r.text}")
    if r.status_code == 200:
        json = r.json()
        print(f"JSON=\"{json}\"")
    '''
    print("========================================")

def api_me_get3(token):
    print("========================================")
    print("Sending 3rd GET request to get protected data of me")

    oauth2_session = OAuth2Session(
        client_id="ySFTzBKLo0XTaK2tQL9ls4Fc",
        client_secret="vq8vMZplY4J00FrxKx4ynV2mhmL2zzjMzP1U2bXZPhQRcmJl",
        token_endpoint_auth_method=None,
        refresh_token_url=_url("/oauth/revoke"),
        refresh_token_params=None,
        scope="profile",
        redirect_uri=None,
        token=token,
        token_placement='header',
        state=None,
        token_updater=None
    )

    r = oauth2_session.request("GET", _url("/api/me"), withhold_token=False, auth=None)

    print(f"Request: \"{r}\"")

    print(f"RESPONSE {r.status_code}")
    print(f"r.url={r.url}")
    print(f"r.text={r.text}")
    if r.status_code == 200:
        json = r.json()
        print(f"JSON=\"{json}\"")

#    new_token = oauth2_client.fetch_access_token();
#    print(f"New token \"{new_token}\"")
    # FORM data
    '''
    payload = {
        "token":f"{token}"
    }
    print(f"PAYLOAD=\"{payload}\"")
    r = requests.get(_url(f"/api/me"), data=payload, params=payload)
    print(f"RESPONSE {r.status_code}")
    print(f"r.url={r.url}")
    print(f"r.text={r.text}")
    if r.status_code == 200:
        json = r.json()
        print(f"JSON=\"{json}\"")
    '''
    print("========================================")
```

Answer (score 1):

OAuthClient is used to create framework integrations. For instance:

- https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/flask.html
- https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/django.html

Comment: Am I correct thinking that if I want to make a request, I have to create instance of `client = OAuthClient(...)`, and then use client.get(), client.post(), etc?? Because this doesn't work for me. It only works with `session = OAuth2Session(...)`. But with session... I don't understand why do I need session if I want to make individual requests.